# Why does creating a ngram from a DTM take so much memory

Tags: r, memory-management, n-gram

I am working on a text prediction model that uses Ngrams. I have a text document (Tweets) that I convert into a DTM. The DTM is 7.3Mb. I wish to convert it to a Ngram using the following code;

```
createNgramTable <- function(x)
{
  m <- matrix(nrow = x$ncol, ncol = 2)
  m[,1] <- x$dimnames$Terms
  m[,2] <- colSums(as.matrix(x))
  colnames(m) <- c("ngram", "freq")
  m <- m[order(m[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]
  return(m)
}
```

This code creates a matrix with the term as column 1 and the number of occurrences as column 2. I then sort it for good measure. It works on small datasets, however, when I run it on the DTM mentioned above it fails. R tries to allocate more than the 8Gb of RAM that I have to execute this function. What am I doing that is such a memory hog and how can I avoid doing it?

Here is the `str()` for the DTM:

```
List of 6
 $ i       : int [1:226963] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ j       : int [1:226963] 9142 22286 25985 5235 6822 8736 10336 15883 
20888 22652 ...
 $ v       : num [1:226963] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ nrow    : int 23601
 $ ncol    : int 44619
 $ dimnames:List of 2
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:23601] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:44619] "''iran" "''true" "''when" "'-)" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
 - attr(*, "weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you want to have the sum of the number of occurrences throughout all Docs, instead of doing a colSums on the DTM, could you create a DTM on a Corpus comprised of all Docs taken together?

Comment: `as.matrix(x)` creates a matrix of 23601x44619 which is 4GB minimum

Answer (score 0):

Without much more information, I cannot say much but my guess is it is either one of these statements: `m[,2] <- colSums(as.matrix(x))` or `m[order(m[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]`.

Some questions you might want to consider are: Do you have to convert it to a matrix? Do you have to pass a list? Why not use a leaner approach or a reference type like data.table to conserve memory?

Hope this helps!